# ArrayList Into String

Tags: android

I have a `Activity` that pulls an `Array` from the previous `Activity`. I can use this code below which gets the `Array` from the previous `Activity` and puts it into a `TextView`.

**Update using `initWheel(R.id.passw_1, names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));` fixed the problem**

```
ArrayList<String> names = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("KEY");

    TextView et2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et2.setText("");
    if (names.size() > 0) {
        for (String str : names) {
            et2.append(str + "    ");
        }
    }
```

This works fine but is not what I need exactly. Instead of it populating a `TextView` I need it to fill a `String` which is like this

`initWheel(R.id.passw_1, "ArrayList Here");`

I have another which will be set by default in the code that looks like this and I need the array to populate the one above in the same format:

`initWheel(R.id.passw_2, new String[] { "Foo", "Bar" });`

Comment: What exactly does "initWheel" do?

Comment: Well it is a wheel that can be spun around so for `R.id.passw_2` it fills the wheel with values "foo" and "bar"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking about getting string array from arraylist, if so please use following method:

```
String[] strArr = list.toArray();
```

Comment: I dont quite understand how to implement that?

Comment: Assuming the ArrayList is named `names` you could do `initWheel(R.id.passw_2, names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));`

Comment: @Jens that makes more sense would that output it exactly like `initWheel(R.id.passw_2, new String[] { "Foo", "Bar" });`

Comment: Yes, the return value of the `names.toArray(new String[names.size()])` call is a String[], i.e. exactly what you are passing when you pass `new String[]{"foo","bar"}`.

Comment: @Jens Cool Ill give it a test now :)

Comment: @Jens Worked fine :) can you join me in a quick chat?